# Where is skbuff.h file in Ubuntu?

Tags: c, linux, header-files

I read in many books that path for skbuff.h is usr/include/linux. I searched in Ubuntu, fedora and backtrack but can't find the header file. Can anybody help me to find this file? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is part of the kernel's source code, so you very likely don't have it installed by default.

Here's how you find out which package(s) owns the file:

```
~$ dpkg -S skbuff.h
linux-headers-2.6.32-22: /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-22/include/linux/skbuff.h
linux-headers-2.6.32-22-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-22-generic/include/linux/skbuff.h
linux-headers-2.6.32-23: /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-23/include/linux/skbuff.h
linux-headers-2.6.32-23-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-23-generic/include/linux/skbuff.h
linux-headers-2.6.32-24: /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-24/include/linux/skbuff.h
linux-headers-2.6.32-24-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-24-generic/include/linux/skbuff.h
```

So you should simply install the required package, to add the file to your computer.

On Ubuntu, you'd do:

```
$ sudo apt install linux-headers-generic
```

The trailing `-generic` is the meta-package, which will have your headers update automatically as new ones become available. [See this Ubuntu answer, too](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75709/how-do-i-install-kernel-header-files/268710#268710).

Comment: @narayanpatra can you please elaborate how you fixed this issue ? i mean how to install skbuff.h ?

Comment: @unwind I need to use skbuff in my kernel modules .. so what i need to do ?